# Getting "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429" error in <iframe>...</iframe> What is the solution?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, http-status-code-429

I'm using `'iframe'` in php file, My code is:-

`<iframe style="height: 448px;" id="iframecode" onload="" src="http://instaembedder.com/gallery.php?username=creatvsj&amp;hashtag=&amp;width=100&amp;cols=2&amp;frame=1&amp;image_border=5&amp;rows=3&amp;cell_margin=8&amp;display_username=1&amp;likes=1&amp;comments=1&amp;date=0&amp;link=0&amp;caption=0&amp;color=gray" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="234"></iframe>`

It shows an error:

> file_get_contents(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=creatvsj&access_token=1427961184.11661b6.57259407a6e349a8aa60b2ad7266ceb2):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 - in
>   /homepages/40/d514764673/htdocs/gallery.php on line 97
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /homepages/40/d514764673/htdocs/gallery.php on line 99

What is the solution???

Comment: **429: Too Many Requests** ... you've spammed it and they've blocked you?

Comment: **400: Bad request** This is the error code I detected

Comment: I see that your request headers are malformed, some of them do not follow the headers rule

Comment: what is the solution?